# Alternative formulation of the supremum norm?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

The supremum norm is defined as

$$\|f\|_\infty=\sup\limits_X|f|$$

This induces a topology:
$$
\begin{align}f_n\overset\infty\to g&\Leftrightarrow \sup\limits_X|f_n-g|\overset{\mathbb{R}}\to 0\\
&\Leftrightarrow\forall\epsilon>0\exists n:\sup\limits_X|f_n-g|<\epsilon\\
&\Leftrightarrow\forall\epsilon>0\exists n\forall x \in X:g(x)-\epsilon<f_n(x)<g(x)+\epsilon
\end{align}$$

I am now in the following very similar situation: 
$$\begin{align}\phantom{f_n\overset\infty\to g}&\phantom{\Leftrightarrow}\forall a>1\exists n\forall x \in X:g(x)\cdot a^{-1}<f_n(x)<g(x)\cdot a\end{align}$$
**Question:** Does a topology $\tau$ exists such that: 
$$\begin{align}f_n\overset\tau\to g&\Leftrightarrow\forall a>1\exists n\forall x \in X:g(x)\cdot a^{-1}<f_n(x)<g(x)\cdot a\end{align}$$
If it exists: does it have a name or is it induced by a norm?

Comment: Presumably you don't want to take logs (even if your functions were positive).

Comment: @Jonas, Do you mean that $f_n\overset\tau\to g\Leftrightarrow\log f_n\overset\infty\to\log g$?

Comment: Right, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Jonas, Thank you! I understand. Do you happen to know if a norm exists that corresponds to this topology?

Comment: I presume not, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this convergence induced by a topology? Yes, every collection of sets can be extended to be a topology, such that convergence in that topology corresponds to "convergence only checking your initial collection". Now choose as initial collection all sets as you describe where you let $f g$ and $a$ vary.

Does this topology have a name? Not that I know of.

Is this convergence induced by a norm? No. The constant functions $ f_n\equiv 1+1/n $ satisfy $ f_n\to 1$ but not $ f_n-1\to 0$

Comment: How can this type of convergence not be induced by a norm if we have $f_n\overset\infty\to f\Leftrightarrow e^{f_n}\overset\tau\to e^f\Leftrightarrow f_n\overset\tau\to f$? The first equivalence follows from the comment of Jonas and the second from continuous functions preserve limits.

Comment: The second equivalence is not true. It is true that $\phi(x_n)\to \phi(x)$ when $x_n\to x$ and $\phi$ is continuous. However, in your case, $\phi$ is the map $f\mapsto e^f$ (with $f$ a function!) and this is not continuous with respect to the topology I wrote down (it also is not continuous with respect to usual function norms, like the $L^2$ norm for example)

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I found a counter-example for $f_n\overset\tau\to f\Rightarrow f_n\overset\infty\to f$, but failed to find a counter-example for $f_n\overset\infty\to f\Rightarrow f_n\overset\tau\to f$. Do you happen to know if this implication holds?