# When is a topology is defined for this special kind of uniform convergence?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

**Question:** Let $\phi:X\to X$ be bijective and continuous. Does a topology $\tau$ exist such that
$$f_n\overset\tau\to f\Leftrightarrow \phi\circ f_n\overset\infty\to\phi\circ f$$
where $\infty$ designates the topology induced by the uniform norm.

**Attempt:** For $\phi=\log$ this is the case, by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1661710/34067). But I don't understand why: defining necessary and sufficient conditions for a sequence to converge (i.e. $f_n\to f\Leftrightarrow\cdots$) does not always induce a topology $\tau$ in which convergence ($f_n\overset\tau\to f$) corresponds to the convergence defined $f_n\to f$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19681/34067)).